# how to fetch nearby location?

Tags: android

I want to fetch the places of 20 meters using current latitude and longitude and display in list(without showing in google map).

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of stuff you need some web service from where you can post lat. and long. and get rss/xml/json response and parsing it you can have your locations.

Comment: can u please tell me from where i get these webservices.

Answer (score 0):

There are some data provider that you can use their APIs to fetch XML file based on your location and, radian and specific POI category. your can try [yelp API](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation), [yahoo location API](http://developer.yahoo.com/everything.html) and also google place API.